# How to refresh an album without re-generating thumbnails in Digikam?

Tags: digikam

In Digikam, I can right-click on an album name, and hit REFRESH. This will do two things:

- It will scan the album directory for new files, and add them to Digikam
- It will create new thumbnails for all photos in the album

I am looking for a way to scan an album for new files, WITHOUT having Digikam create new thumbnails for existing files. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you share the version of Digikam to replicate the problem?

Comment: How did you realize new thumbnails were beign created?

Comment: Version 7.5.0
I realize new thumbnails were being created because Digikam reports that it is creating new thumbnails (popup appears) in addition to scanning for new items, and I can also see the thumbnails being refreshed (they go white and then reappear).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/digikam-doc/digikam/using-setup.html#using-setup-misc), this may be "skip automatically"; which at least skips the image file:

[image: screenshot behavior]

Observing `thumbnails-digikam.db` (depending on the storage backend) would show what really changes. It's all about [`Digikam.ThumbnailCreator`](https://www.digikam.org/api/classDigikam_1_1ThumbnailCreator.html) ~[`thumbnailcreator.cpp`](https://github.com/KDE/digikam/blob/master/core/libs/threadimageio/thumb/thumbnailcreator.cpp) & [`thumbnailcreator.h`](https://github.com/KDE/digikam/blob/master/core/libs/threadimageio/thumb/thumbnailcreator.h), which may need to be controlled differently, in order to skip the generation of "thumbnails for existing files". This seems to be the repository: [`KDE/digikam`](https://github.com/KDE/digikam). Not sure if they accept feature request there, but usually one can raise an "issue" and provide a "pull request", which may close the issue, in case it's being accepted. When unnecessary processing can be skipped, this is usually a good reason. Changing the storage backend to MySQL, may generally speed up the indexing process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not sure how to interpret this. I found the screenshot you included above in the manual, but it's listed under "Camera Settings". My question is not linked to importing files from a camera (in fact, I don't import my photos directly from the camera). As far as I can understand, the SKIP AUTOMATICALLY option has no link to thumbnail generation when refreshing an album. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

A way to implement this is Importing all the files insted of Rfreshing. Right click -> "Import" -> "Import from remote storage...". Then select the same directory ("Select import location") you want to update and import all the images. You can skip automatically the ones with same name (the ones you do not need to really import).

It is by far not an optimal solution. But works

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. That would be a workaround but indeed not an optimal one. But if there is no other way, then this will have to do..